# Fix fonts through ssh

Tags: ssh, fonts

There seems to be some problems with the font size when connecting remotely to another Xserver using ssh.

I am using manjaro linux and awesomewm. As far as I understand, the local font settings are being controled by `lxappearance` as the changes in the settings done there affect my system. However, when I open a remote X window using a command like

```
ssh -t -Y remotepc '/home/me/.local/sources/eclipse/eclipse'
```

I seems that the fonts are being rendered by the remote computer, making very uncomfortable different sizes among my windows. As seen on the next snapshot, on the left size I have proper font sizes (locally) whereas on the right side fonts are huge (remotely).

[image: example]

Does anyone have a clue on how can I render the remote fonts locally?

UPDATE: The problem seems to be a bit different than I thought. If I run `gnome-settings-daemon` a set of applications change towards normal font size (for instance Eclipse) and another set transforms to tiny sizes (what seems to be controlled by lxappearance), as seen in the next two snapshots. Any suggestion?

using gnome-settings-daemon:

[image: using gnome-settings-daemon]

without gnome-settings-daemon

[image: without gnome-settings-daemon]